# Erlang distribution variable rate

Tags: probability, distributions, exponential-distribution

I have a data set I suspect can be modeled by some variation of the Erlang distribution, with shape a constant $k=2$, but the rate/scale a (known but not constant) function of the independent variable (time, in my case).

I'm looking for a probability density function and cumulative distribution function for this case, or pointers toward how I could derive them myself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Formulas for PDF and CDF of Erlang distribution are on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution. Specializing to k=2 should be trivial.

Comment: True, but those pdf and cdf formulas appear to assume a constant scale/rate parameter. The average of my values increases with increasing time, and since I know k is a constant of 2 in my data, I'm therefore looking for something that allows for the scale/rate to be a non-constant function of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Erlang is just a Gamma with integer shape parameter, modelling the scale as a function of some other variable would be easily accomplished via a Gamma generalized linear model (GLM).

The Gamma GLM would directly model the mean (= shape x scale) but with fixed shape (which is the case for Gamma GLMs), the same model (up to a constant scaling factor) is also a model for the scale.

Common link functions for the Gamma (which relates the mean of the variable to the linear function of predictors) are log, inverse (the canonical link) and identity. If your known relationship fits with one of those it will be particularly easy to set up (though other functions would be possible).

It is not necessary to estimate the shape parameter to fit the model but you'll need it if you want a fitted scale parameter (rather than a fitted mean).

[If you use R, the MASS library (which comes with R but is not loaded by default) contains a function to estimate the shape parameter via maximum likelihood; this will allow a maximum likelihood estimate of scale for a Gamma model -- divide any fitted mean by the shape parameter. But if you definitely want an Erlang rather than a gamma and you definitely need to estimate scale specifically (rather than the mean of the response), you'd need to identify which of the integer shape parameters had the higher likelihood.]

Comment: This is likely to turn out to be the right way to go. Thank you!